# PHP Mail function not working with Google Workspace Email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, google-workspace

I have tried a few different methods, but php mail() and PHPMailer are not sending to my google workspace email addresses. They will send to my yahoo and gmail address, though.

My domain is in google domains, and the website is on GoDaddy. I also want to point out the google workspace email is NOT the same as the domain I'm using the contact forms on.

So far, I've tried adding txt SPF records for GoDaddy to my domain. I was told to use these two.

Host | Type | Data

```
@ | txt | "v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all"
admin| txt | "v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all"
```

These SPF records were given to me to use by GoDaddy reps.

I tested different php mail functions i've found online just to make sure it wasn't my code, and version 5.2 and 6.6 of PHPMailer. (I still have issues with PHPMailer SMTP but I'll tackle that after I get this issue fixed.)

The only other thing I can think of is trying this on a different server, but I don't have one to test on.

Has anyone ran into this issue? I'm at a loss.

Example Code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$from = 'Darth Vader <darth@empire.com>';
$to = 'Emperor <palpatine@empire.com>';
$subject = 'Force';
$message = 'There is a great disturbance in the Force.';
$headers = 'From: ' . $from;

if (!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Error.";
}
else
{
    echo "Message sent.";
}
```

Obviously with my own creds.

***UPDATE***

I also added DMARC to my txt record last night. I tested it 16 hours later, no luck.

I replaced my actual domain with the word "domain"

```
"v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:no-reply@domain; ruf=mailto:no-reply@domain; fo=1;"
```

***UPDATE 2***
SPF Record is now

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:secureserver.net -all
```

I've waited until it propagated, still no luck.

Comment: From your question I gather that emailing from your server is possible, but I cannot see whether you have a valid SPF record, it seems weird to me, and it is also unclear whether you send the email using the domain which has the SPF record in the FROM address. Can you makes these things more explicit in your question?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I do use a no-reply@domain email address for the contact forms. And it does send to the other address types that I mentioned so I have confirmed that it does send emails. (Hosting is GoDaddy).

As for the SPF records, I'll try to fix that above so it's clearer for you.

Comment: OK, thank you. The SPF looks good now, and you seem to be using the correct domain. I assume the domain you're talking about is the domain associated with the web server on which you run the PHP script, not the domain associated with your Google Workspace Email address? Did you check the spam folder? I'm sorry, but I have to check these basic things. I saw your update. DMARC is rather complex, I'm not sure that single DNS line will do it. However, you can [test your mail server here](https://internet.nl/test-mail/?invalid), which is very useful.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware so google told me to change my SPF to this and try it again. "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:_secureserver.net ~all"

Yeah the domain with the web site contact form is where I made the changes to the SPF, the google workspace email is a different domain. I checked the spam, the logs and searched for the email too. I'll check out your link here soon as I can.

Comment: Your updated SPF record makes little sense. What you include are the additional domains that you allow to send emails on behalf of your domain. So if your mail server is hosted on GoDaddy then [include:secureserver.net](https://www.godaddy.com/help/use-spf-records-to-prevent-spoofing-and-ensure-mail-delivery-40499) makes sense, under the conditions mentioned, but you will never send through Google so `include:_spf.google.com` makes no sense. To get mail working properly you've got to understand how things work.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware that's what I thought, too. But between google and godaddy support, neither could tell me a proper responses other than "that record should work".

I did want to eventually move to sending from a google address but I guess updating to google at that time would fix the issue. I'll change the spf record to just secureserver.net